# Find a Fourier series to represent the function exp(x) for x belongs to (-pi,pi) and hence derive pi/sinh(pi).

Tags: fourier-series

Find a Fourier series to represent the function exp(x) for x belongs to $(-\pi, \pi)$ and hence derive $frac{\pi}{\sinh(\pi)}$.

Unable to derive the pi over sinh(pi) part...how do I do it?

Comment: First: Use MathJax. Second, show us the Fourier series you got.

Comment: I do not know how to use mathjax.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Find 
$$a_0=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^x dx$$
$$a_n=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^x\cos(nx) dx$$
$$b_n=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^x\sin(nx) dx$$
then
$$S(f)(x)=\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx)$$